# How to make "security" - attributes on classes in C#?

Tags: c#, attributes

I want to make custom attributes on classes to restrict who calls them.

For example:

```
[Permission("Admin")]
public class MyData {
....
```

How to do that?  So I want to really make some sort of Permission-class.

Comment: You will need to create a class which inherits the `Attribute` class

Comment: Do you want them to do anything? Or are they just for decoration that you mybe check manually via reflection?

Comment: Actually I wouldn't need to write anything custom. The PrincipalPermission is what I was in need for.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[MSDN Custom Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Here is a link to what is needed to create custom attributes.

Comment: This reference is too old and not useful.

Answer (score 4):

You either use the ones that already exist, or you write your own and hook them into the Code Access Security architecture. This has been around for a really long time, and I was able to find these articles:

[Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0.aspx)

[Creating Your Own Code Access Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yctbsyf4.aspx)

Cut-away from the link above:

> Implementing a custom code access permission involves the following
> steps, some of which are optional. Each step is described in a
> separate topic.
>
> 1. Design the `Permission` class.
> 2. Implement the `IPermission` and `IUnrestrictedPermission` interfaces.
> 3. Implement the `ISerializable` interface, if necessary for performance or to support special data types.
> 4. Handle XML encoding and decoding.
> 5. Add support for declarative security, by implementing an `Attribute` class.
> 6. Demand custom permission for your permission, where appropriate.

It's really steps 1, 2, 5 and 6 that are of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Permission would inherit from Attribute. Then you would need to implement code to inspect the class for these attributes before calling the class/method. the .net framework already has this functionality built in.
SecurityPermissionAttribute and FileIOPermissionAttribute are two implementations you may want to consider before rolling your own.